# Why is my React Router loader function running twice on app initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am implementing a new React Router using `createBrowserRouter`.  I am noticing that when I load my app the `loader` function runs twice.

Is this expected? If not what would be causing it?

Here is my implementation of the router:

```
async function defaulNewAPIs(
  appTypeId: string,
  email: string,
  submissionId: string
) {
  console.log('running')
  const [reasonTypes, authToken, submissionDetails] = await Promise.all([
    getReasonTypes(),
    getAuthJWT(email),
    getSubmission(appTypeId, submissionId),
  ])
  reasonTypes?.forEach((item: ReasonType) => {
    item.name = item.reasonText
    item.value = item.reasonTypeID
  })
  const decoded = jwtDecode(authToken.token)

  return reasonTypes || null
}

const createRouter = (email: string) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/:appTypeId/:submissionId',
      element: <AppLayout />,
      id: 'root',
      loader: ({ params }) => {
        const { appTypeId, submissionId } = params as ReferralParams
        return defaulNewAPIs(appTypeId, email, submissionId)
      },
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <ReferralDetails status="new" />,
        },
      ],
    },
  ])

const AppRoutes: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ msalContext }: AppProps) => {
  const email = msalContext.accounts[0].username

  return <RouterProvider router={createRouter(email)} />
}

export default withMsal(AppRoutes)
```

`withMsal` is a context provider.

This component is then called in my main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <GenReMsal>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthenticatedTemplate>
        <AppRoutes />
      </AuthenticatedTemplate>
      <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        <GenReLogin />
      </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </GenReMsal>
)
```

Comment: When running in dev mode, components will re-render twice when using `StrictMode`. See https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode